# send JSON object from handwritten javascript to GWT server side

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt

I know how to send data from the client java class (the entrypoint) in the GWT project but how do i send JSON object from handwritten javascript to GWT server side

Comment: JSNI should do your work. - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Answer (score 0):

*If you know how to send data from the client java class (the entrypoint) in the GWT project* then a better way is to use `GWT JSNI`

**You can use [GWT JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) to call Java method from JavaScript and vice-verse.**

**You have to just export you `Java` method to `JavaScript`.** Now in Java you have full control to do anything.

---

Find a sample code on [Calling GWT Java function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080099/calling-gwt-java-function-from-javascript)

Comment: Is your issue resolved using JSNI? I hope now you have learned it that how to use JSNI export feature in GWT?