# How to I expose a Java class's functionality via some JavaScript interface in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

Say I have a Java class `Course` that has some method `testMethod`.  How do I expose this functionality such that I can interact with it using hand-written JavaScript as follows:

```
someCourse.testMethod();
```

where `someCourse` is passed directly from the Java code via a native method, like:

```
private native void AssociateCourse(Course course) /*-{
    someCourse = course;
}-*/;
```

The main issue I am having in achieving this is that GWT does not provide any way for me to access the prototype of the `Course` constructor.  For example, the following is invalid:

```
private native void Expose() /*-{
    $wnd.Course = @mypackage.Course;
}-*/;
```

because it expects it to access some field, not the whole thing.

I would like to avoid using a library like gwt exporter because I feel that having to incorporate that into my source code which handles application logic will make it difficult to separate those two aspects of my code, which will be a bad thing if the code were shared between a GWT project like this and an Android application, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GWT 2.7+ you can use the new JSInterop. It is hidden behind a compiler flag, but works quite well.

It is still experimental and may change in future releases.

Take a look at this demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFMD1GXR2Tg

Answer (score 0):

Well there are [different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080099/calling-gwt-java-function-from-javascript/16081350#16081350) you can accomplish your problem, and it depends as well of the amount of stuff you have to expose.

If it is just a couple of methods I would use pure JSNI or `gQuery`.

As the answer to your question, in your class constructor you can expose methods for new instances (I would not modify the java class prototype though):

```
public class Course  {
    public Course() {
        exportMethods(this);
    }
    public String testMethod(String s) {
        return s;
    }
    private native void exportMethods(Course c) /*-{
        this.testMethod = c.@mypackage.Course::testMethod(*);
    }-*/;
}
```

As you say `gwt-exporter` implies to include a dependency, but if you are going to deal with a lot of exported methods, properties, and callbacks it is worth.

The new stuff [JsInterop](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-web-toolkit-contributors/Dwdk-aEHs8Y/OvSNe6egUekJ) available in 2.7.0 is very experimental, it lacks a lot of features and you have to enable it using a experimental compiler flag in the compiler, it would be almost usable in 2.8.0 but still experimental until 3.0.0, so I would not trust on it for production projects.

Comment: Would this result in a redundant implementation of the `testMethod` on every instance of a Course, rather than just one on some shared object like its prototype?